# Search lines of a file and replace variable with a value in an array and loop through until array has no more values

Tags: ruby, arrays, substitution

I think I'm close here but there is a key piece eluding me.

#### template.txt

> I am a @file
>   that needs
>   the word file replaced
>   with each value in an array

#### subvalues.txt

> word1
>   word2
>   word3
>   word4

So what I'm doing is opening a file to append to using

```
filex = file.new ("outputfile.txt" "a")
```

Then I open the file with the template data with

```
data = file.open("template.txt")
```

Then I import my data into an array with

```
array1 = File.readlines("subvalues.txt")
```

and here is where I'm getting stuck.  How do I loop through the array, substitute `@file` in `file1` with the first element in the array, write the output to `outputfile.txt`, substitute `@file` in `file1` again with the second element in the array, append the output to `outputfile.txt`, and continue until the array has no more values.

I have found similar posts but nothing that matches what I'm doing.  I've tried adapting some of those ideas to what I'm trying to do but it seems like I'm doing something backwards and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you provide a sample final result for the output file?

Answer (score 2):

template.txt :

```
I am a @file that needs the word file replaced with each value in an array
```

subvalues.txt

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

Code:

```
data = File.open('template.txt', &:read)
array = File.read('subvalues.txt').split
File.open('outputfile.txt', 'a') do |file|
  array.each do |value|
    file.write(data.gsub('@file', value))
  end 
end
```

Comment: Now that is far more elegant than what I was doing.  Is it terribly obvious that I'm still learning.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a simple, hacky if you want, way.

```
substitutions_array.each do |elt|
  big_file.sub('file', elt)
end
```

It may not be the best way but it should work well for you. Sub does only one replacement so you can loop through your array.

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question, if that's the case see the answer above.